# Return type hinting from function parameter

Tags: typescript

How can I provide return type hinting from a function parameter?

```
class BaseClass {
   constructor(private logger:Logger){}
}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
   public helloWorld() {
      console.log('Hello World')
   }
}

function buildInstance<T extends BaseClass>(target: typeof BaseClass, logger: Logger): T {
  logger.defaults.meta = { path: __dirname }
  return new target(logger) as T
}

const instance = buildInstance<ChildClass>(ChildClass)
instance.helloWorld() // instance is understood to be ChildClass instance
```

The above works, in so far as, `instance` is type hinted for ChildClass correctly, but I feel like that is messy and I might be missing something.  Is there someway to simply my function / call signatures to infer return type from the argument.  Or conversely, is there a way to infer `new target` from the type argument?

Comment: This code doesn't seem to be a [mcve].  What is `args` here?  I can imagine `BaseClass` is some unspecified class whose implementation you've left out, but should I be thinking that `args` is some set of arguments applicable to any subclass constructor whatsoever?  I'd be inclined to rewrite your `buildInstance()` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/OwEQgw), using a construct signature type for `target`, but without better example code you can see I'm just guessing about what you're doing.

Comment: Updated my question to contain more code.  The intent of `buildInstance` is be a factory function that configures classes that extend `BaseClass`, in a similar fashion.

Comment: Changing the function signature from `typeof BaseClass` to `new (...args: any[]) => T` allows me to accomplish what I wanted.  I'm not sure why.

Comment: Don't use a type parameter that isn't used in typing any value parameters. That is a red flag 99.9% of the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare your function as `buildInstance<T>(type: T): T`, you're telling TypeScript that `type` is an *instance* of `T` (the same type that is returned, the instance type). But you want to pass a class into it, hence you need to express that. `buildInstance<T>(type: Class<T>): T` satisfies this.

Demo: https://repl.it/@chvolkmann/DimgrayGiddyVertex

```
// something that can be constructed with "new", returning T
type Class<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T

class Vehicle {}
class Car extends Vehicle {}
class Truck extends Vehicle {}


function buildVehicle<T extends Vehicle>(Type: Class<T>) : T {
  return new Type()
}

const car = buildVehicle(Car) // type: Car
const truck = buildVehicle(Truck) // type: Truck
```

Here is the same example, but slightly more involved. Here, also the arguments you can pass to the respective class are type checked. **Might require TypeScript 4+** for all that generic jazz.

```
// something that can be constructed with "new", accepting argument of type A, returning T
type Class<T, A extends any[] = any[]> = new (...args: A) => T

class Vehicle {
  constructor(x: number) {}
}
class Car extends Vehicle {}
class Truck extends Vehicle {}


function buildVehicle<T extends Vehicle, A extends any[]>(Type: Class<T, A>, ...args: A) : T {
  // args is type checked!
  // A is a tuple of whatever Vehicle expects as constructor argument types
  return new Type(...args)
}

// compiles fine
let car = buildVehicle(Truck, 42) 

// TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
car = buildVehicle(Car) 

//  TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
car = buildVehicle(Truck, 'foobar')
```